# c++ compare std::string won't work if I don't compile with Code::Blocks but cygwin

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin, compare, stdstring

I'm coding a class that should read OFF Files and I'm having the following issue:

If I compile it within the Code::Blocks environment everything works fine.
If the first line of the file that is to be loaded differs from "OFF" it will jump into the second if-statement and exit the program...

However if I compile with g++ in cygwin the program jumps into the second if-Statement no matter what is actually written in the file.
Any Suggestions?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

polyeder offManager::readOFF(std::string filename)
{
    //Open File
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str());

// If file couldn't be opened
if( !file.is_open() )
{
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Konnte Datei \""
    << filename << "\" nicht oeffnen!"
    << std::endl;
    exit (2);
}


// Test if the file really is an OFF File
std::string line;
std::string off ("OFF");
getline( file, line );
if ( line.compare(off) != 0 )
{
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Datei \""
    << filename << "\" ist nicht im OFF Format!"
    << std::endl;
    file.close();
    exit (2);
}
...
}
```

If I type g++ -v in cygwin I get the following:
Blablabla
Thread-Modell: posix
gcc-Version 4.5.3 (GCC)

Code::Blocks uses this version:
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.4.1 (TDM-2 mingw32)

Comment: You didn't check if `getline` succeeded.

Comment: In the output diagnostics, output the value of `line`, so you can see what it contains. It doesn't end in `'\n'`, does it? By the way, you should `#include <cstdlib>` rather than `<stdlib.h>` in a C++ program. And your indentation is terrible.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I have replaced the header ... don't know why my indentation is that terrible though ;)

Comment: Well, you indent the first two lines in the function by 4 spaces, but the rest of the function content isn't indented at all, so when glancing over the source, it looks like the function has ended there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are opening is likely in DOS text format, so it's lines end with `\r\n`, rather than just `\n`.

The Cygwin FAQ has an entry about [this issue](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.api.cr-lf). I copied your code into a simple `main` driver, and compiled it two ways. First, the regular way:

```
$ g++ s.cc
$ ./a.exe test
ERROR: Datei "test" ist nicht im OFF Format!
```

And then, with the suggested fix (open with text translation mode, write with binary mode):

```
$ g++ s.cc /usr/lib/automode.o 
$ ./a.exe test
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful! Will it work without the suggested fixes under most unix environments though(Means is it only cygwin dependant?)?

Comment: @user1525814: Yes. The fix is only for Cygwin.